# MYSQL INSERTION SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: mysql, facebook

I've been trying to come up with a facebook app that would retrieve data from facebook users, however I'm having trouble with my sql insert into... code below:

```
    foreach($groups['data'] as $group){
        $gid=GetSQLValueString($group['id'], "text");
        $name=GetSQLValueString($group['name'], "text");

        echo $gid." -> ".$name;

        $iquery = sprintf("INSERT INTO group(gid, name) values(%s,%s)", $gid, $name);
        $ires = mysql_query($iquery) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "huhuhu<br />\n$sql");
    }
```

which throws this error: 
        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group(gid, name) values('463827760382367','MY FRIENDSSSSSSSSS')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` is a MySQL reserved word. Ideally you should change the table name, but you can just wrap the name in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `group` (gid, name) values(%s,%s)
```